# What is "nroff macro" in Vim?

Tags: vim

It seems to link to sections in Vim.

I have searched the help and didn't find it.

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRDdP.png)

Comment: Links to images are very frowned upon; post text whenever possible over images, and images whenever practical over image links.

Answer (score 1):

Just like `switch` is nothing in Vim, but something in C/PHP/... that Vim should know about (via the `cinwords` setting), "nroff macro" is nothing in Vim, but something in `nroff`, where Vim wants to know which nroff macros are section macros, and which are paragraph macros, in order to process groff files correctly.

Thus, e.g. `SHNHH HUnhsh`, the default value of the `sections` setting, defines `.SH`, `.NH`, `.H`, `.HU`, `.nh` and `.sh` as character sequences that should be considered to separate sections of text, when such are encountered in a nroff file.

To see an example of a nroff file, see any manpage file directly (i.e. not through `man`); e.g. `/usr/share/man/man1/nroff.1`. Read `man 7 groff` for more details on the language itself, if you wish.